# Firebase Phone Authentication Android gives Error NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.isStateSaved

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm implementing Firebase Google and Phone Authentication in my app.
Sign-In with Google Working fine. But Phone Authentication giving

> Error: NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.isStateSaved

I'm using Firebase and Firebase-UI in Android

That's the APP Level Build Gradle File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dev_man_team.fiverr.predictnwin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
       }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And that's the code

```
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_login);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User is Already Signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{

        signUp();
    }
}

private void signUp() {
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build());
    providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build());
    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(providers).build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the Error I recieved

> 11-15 20:48:12.509 9712-9712/com.dev_man_team.fiverr.predictnwin E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.isStateSaved
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CompletableProgressDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(CompletableProgressDialog.java:51)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CompletableProgressDialog.show(CompletableProgressDialog.java:41)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneVerificationActivity.showLoadingDialog(PhoneVerificationActivity.java:390)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneVerificationActivity.verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneVerificationActivity.java:157)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.onNext(VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.java:200)
>                                                                                             at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.onActivityResult(VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.java:184)
>                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5387)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-15 20:48:12.769 9712-9712/com.dev_man_team.fiverr.predictnwin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.isStateSaved
>                                                                                          at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CompletableProgressDialog.showAllowingStateLoss(CompletableProgressDialog.java:51)
>                                                                                          at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.CompletableProgressDialog.show(CompletableProgressDialog.java:41)
>                                                                                          at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneVerificationActivity.showLoadingDialog(PhoneVerificationActivity.java:390)
>                                                                                          at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.PhoneVerificationActivity.verifyPhoneNumber(PhoneVerificationActivity.java:157)
>                                                                                          at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.onNext(VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.java:200)
>                                                                                          at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.phone.VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.onActivityResult(VerifyPhoneNumberFragment.java:184)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5387)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks in advance for correcting my mistakes.
I will appreciate Your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three suggestions:

(1) You are using FirebaseUI version 3.1.0 with newer version 11.6.0 of  Firebase and Google Play libraries. The [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies) explains that this requires upgrading transitive dependencies.  Following the instructions in the documentation, you should add these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:26.1.0'
```

(2) You are including ALL of Google Play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'
```

This needlessly increases you APK size and build time and will cause your app to exceed the 65K method reference limit on older devices.  Better to only include the specific APIs you need, such as `play-services-auth`. (List of [APIs here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project))

(3) Your build.gradle does not specifiy the `buildToolsVersion`.  I don't know what default is used.  Safer to specify one, for example:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

Comment: I'm still getting same error.
Google Sign-In working fine but phone authentication not.

Comment: @Taimoor: Please update your post to show your build.gradle file after you made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally found answer of my own question after doing lots of search**

With @Bob's three suggestions I added one more thing in my App Level Build Gradle

```
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
}
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0'
}
```

to avoid the conflicts.
Now everything works fine.